# How to substitute environment variables for value

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I'm deploying a node app to heroku and I want to be able to set some env variables, namely the url and keys of some services I'm consuming.

**The problem is** I'm compiling and minifying my client side code using grunt, so the env variables are not available to the scripts, so I'm wondering if there's some grunt tool that can perform this preprocessing or an alternative to get these variables at runtime.

Comment: You could use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and set them in a `.env` file

Comment: That's not the problem: I need a tool that performs substitutions on lines like `process.env.VAR` to `"VALUE"` at deployment time, so they are present on the files.

Answer (score 0):

To work locally, create a `.env` file in the root of your application and set there the variables you want. Also you can set your environment variables to use in deploy using `heroku config:set KEY=value`

Comment: That's not the problem: I need a tool that performs substitutions on lines like `process.env.VAR` to `"VALUE"` at deployment time, so they are present on the files.

Comment: @PedroMontotoGarcía, maybe this resolve your problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-env